# Default value AWS replace with pseudo parameter reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a parameter in an aws cloudformation template

```
 Parameters:
   ExecRole:
     Type: String
     Description: Required. Lambda exec role ARN
     Default: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/lambdaExecRole
```

Assuming the 123456789 is the AcountId I want to use the pseudo parameter reference but I cannot do it, I try the followings without success

```
Default: arn:aws:iam::!Ref{AWS::AccountId}:role/exLambdaExecRole
Default: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/exLambdaExecRole'
```

In the last case is throwing me an error

> Default member must be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this will always be role, why can't you as a parameter ask for the nae to be passed in then use the [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) intrinsic function to replace in the Resources section of your CloudFormation template.

That way your `arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role` part of the arn would not need to be part of the parameter.

Comment: Yes that  works and I did not think in that way, but this let me wondering if I cannot do what I want to do at fist? just to learn a little bit more

Comment: Not in parameters I am afraid

Answer (score 4):

It seems like functions (ex. `!Sub`) are not supported in default values of `Parameters`.

Here's a workaround we're using.

We have a separate stack called `Parameters` which exports whatever parameters needed in other stacks. For instance:

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: Id of the VPC.
    Value: !Ref VpcId
    Export:
      Name: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-VpcId'
```

In other stacks we simply import these exported values:

```
  VpcId: !ImportValue
    'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-VpcId'
```

`EnvType` and `EnvId` are the same for all the stacks of one environment.

With roles you might want to do the following. Create a separate `Roles` template, implement your roles there and export their ARNs:

```
Outputs:
  LambdaExecutionRoleArn:
    Description: ARN of the execution role for the log-and-pass function.
    Value: !GetAtt
      - LambdaExecutionRole
      - Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-roles-LambdaExecutionRole-Arn'
```

Again, in other stack you could simply `ImportValue`:

```
    Role: !ImportValue
      'Fn::Sub': 'stk-${EnvType}-${EnvId}-roles-LogAndPassFunctionExecutionRole-Arn'
```